# Updating a Store record value in sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have a store and have populated with 5 records.
the corresponding model has 6 fields : ordinal, pageNum, top, left, bottom , right.
When i try to update the 4 fields those are top, left, bottom , right for the particular record, lets say i want to update fields(top, left, bottom , right) in the 4 th record and i am setting the record to dirty :

```
 markukRecord = markupStore.getAt(3)
 markupRecord.set('top',topVal);
 markupRecord.dirty = true;

 markukRecord = markupStore.getAt(3)
 markupRecord.set('left',leftVal);
 markupRecord.dirty = true;

 markukRecord = markupStore.getAt(3)
 markupRecord.set('bottom',botVal);
 markupRecord.dirty = true;

 markukRecord = markupStore.getAt(3)
 markupRecord.set('right',rightVal);
 markupRecord.dirty = true;
```

note: the code is not repeated, its running through the loop.
the problem here is , the 'left' and 'right' values are updated to the 5th record but not to the 4th record(index=3).

Am i missing anything here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems very weird that if you're iterating only one item does not get saved... should be the same code for all items..

One thing that you should check:  are you doing `markupStore.sync()` after doing those changes?

Maybe you should show us the complete code, for example, where are `leftVal or rightVal defined? how are they defined, etc.